# ActionBar not visible in fragment

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an AppCompatActivity with this layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frame"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Now I wanna navigate to a Fragment. The fragment is properly loaded, but I can't see the ActionBar. I can open the drawer via the gesture.
I'm a bit puzzled about this, since I only replace the content_frame. Also if I place something else there, for example an FloatingActionButton, it will also be displayed in the fragment.

Layout Fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:windowBackground">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp">
....
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try adding this to the root `LinearLayout` in the layout for your fragment: `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"`

Comment: unfortunately this did just move the content down, without showing the fragment.

Comment: Found it! I had to set the background color to 
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" as well =)

Comment: If you don't want to use the transparent background, use `android:layout_marginTop` instead.